# How should I modify this question?

Tags: discussion

[What service should I use to incorporate in seyschelles?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/what-service-should-i-use-to-incorporate-in-seyschelles)

Basically the problems is as said. And I just want to know if there is a reputable service that I can use.

It seems that prices to incorporate is a bit expensive in Seychelles even though it's a poor country.

I think I shouldn't ask directly for which service is good. Should I change it how do I get good cost effective service for incorporating in Seychelles? Is seychelles even the best place to incorporate?

Comment: When you're at the point of thinking you want to incorporate offshore, to my mind you're already well past the point at which you should be paying an accountant (or similar) for their services

Answer (score 5):

> Is Seychelles even the best place to incorporate?

Your questions are off topic.

- which company to use?
- Which country to use?

We have no idea how your company will measure best.

I don't think there is a way for this site to help you decide how your company should be structured.